# calculate percent with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 variables with different values

```
{{ timelineExpectedAmount }} //1.996.626,32
```

and

```
{{ customTimelineExpectedAmount }} //6.104,77
```

I want to know, how can I calculate how many % `customTimelineExpectedAmount` is from `timelineExpectedAmount`.

I tried this: `{{ timelineExpectedAmount / 100 * customTimelineExpectedAmount }}` but did not work.

any hint ? the expected result is `0.30%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really more of a math question...

```js
var perc = 6104.77 / 1996626.32 * 100;

console.log(perc); // 0.3057542585134308
```

---

**Or, in your case:**

```
{{ customTimelineExpectedAmount / timelineExpectedAmount * 100 }}
```

---

You may want to [round the result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).